# How to though DKMS install new version of ZFS modules to specified already installed kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling, software-sources, zfs, dkms

I know that DKMS provides support for installing supplementary versions of kernel modules. But how I can automatically install newer version of ZFS modules to installed kernels?

I've already have zfs-2.1.5 installed in /usr/src for DKMS, but how I can install newer version?

- Should I compile and build custom DKMS package from sources before putting it into /usr/src/ with created created by myself dkms.conf file?
  https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Developer%20Resources/Custom%20Packages.html
- Should I just compile zfs from source and then put folder with it into /usr/src/ with created by myself dkms.conf file?
  https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Developer%20Resources/Building%20ZFS.html
- Or I can just extract downloaded zfs tar.gz to folder and put it into /usr/src/ with created by myself dkms.conf?

Comment: I am not running zfs to test this out, but I am assuming that it shouldn't be too much different than https://askubuntu.com/a/1334101/231142 but changing the name and driver version to match what you have.